# removing extra pipes (using sed or tr)

Tags: regex, linux, sed, gnu, tr

I have a file that has too many pipes in it, and I want to replace the \n and | sign with *just* a \n.

e.g.

```
first name|last name|blahblah
|
first name|last name|blahblah
|
```

I want it to just be the following (without the extra |)

```
first name|last name|blahblah
first name|last name|blahblah
```

Ideally, I could do this easily with sed or tr (translate). Problem is that when I do it (and think I escape the pipe), it seems to not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is your sed attempt?

Comment: I was doing something like "cat file.txt | sed 's/\"|"/\\n/g'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this to delete (`d`) all lines which begin (`^`) with a pipe.

```
 sed "/^|/d" file
```

Comment: And with some versions of `sed`, adding `-i.bak` will overwrite the original with the modified version.

Answer (score 2):

`grep -v '^|$' filename` works for me:

```
$ grep -v '^|$' <<EOT
> first name|last name|blahblah
> |
> first name|last name|blahblah
> |
> EOT

first name|last name|blahblah
first name|last name|blahblah
```

Explanation:

- `-v` = show lines not matching the pattern
- `^` = begin of the line
- `$` = end of the line

Basically it is filtering out lines with a `|` alone.

I think you can't do it with `tr`, but with `sed` it can be done using the same regular expression.